# how to run a function in child scope after parent scope gets restful data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, scope

My page have parent and child scope. child scope displays a list belongs to a data in parent scope.

For example,

There is a department with three employees. Department is in parent scope and employees are retrieved in the child scope.

The problem is parent scope get the department by restful api call. Then, child scope call another api to get employees in the department.

By doing this, child scope needs to know the department in parent. However, chlid scope api call is often triggered before parent gets the department. So end up displyaing no employees even though there are.

I am seeking a solution for this.

Comment: Can you provide peace of code that you already have?

Comment: Before you make the API call for the employee data in the child scope do a check for the department data to see if it's available, if not don't run the call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch Department model in child scope and whenever you get Department model from your API, You can trigger your employee API.

Basically what i am saying.

1. Pass (Bind) Department model to your child scope.
2. Watch Department Model in child scope.
3. You will get callback whenever Department model changed, So at this point of time you can trigger Employee request.

Another way is you can broadcast the message whenever you get Department data and your child scope must listen this message.

I hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What about [using promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to ensure that the department has been fetched before employees ?

I don't know how your code works, but my idea is that the function that does the department API call should returns a promise, that can be used by the child controller.

```
myApp.controller('DepartmentCtrl', function($scope, $q){  
    $scope.department = '';

    $scope.getDepartment = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // Here, we simulate an HTTP call or another asynchronous operation
        setTimeout(function(){
            $scope.department = 'AnAwesomeDepartment';
            deferred.resolve();
        }, 1500);

        return deferred.promise;
    }
});

myApp.controller('EmployeesCtrl', function($scope, $q){
    $scope.employees = [];

    $scope.getEmployees = function(){
        $scope.$parent.getDepartment().then(
            function(){
                $scope.employees = ['Mark', 'Jane', 'Lisa'];
            }
        );
    }

    // Get everything
    $scope.getEmployees(); 
});
```

[Here's a small fiddle that implements this code.](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17139/)

Of course, you can think to several improvements such as caching the department, or [if you're using ui-router, resolve the departement](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) before entering the child state.

Comment: The child scope will be reused in other pages. So, dependency using function call from child is not a good idea in my case. I like to pass a scope variable from parent to child.